# Is there a general rule for a maximum amount of parallel tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am using parallel tasks for the first time instead of using a traditional threadpool. In my application I allow for the user to input the number of tasks started to complete the job. (jobs can be very big). I noticed that if I allow any more than 10 or so tasks, the application starts to hang and I actually get worse performance due to the resources used.

I am wondering if there is any correlation between amount of processors and max amount of tasks, so that I can limit the maximum amount of tasks for the users pc so it doesn't slow it down.

Comment: I guess it depends on what your threads are doing. Disk I/O access? In-memory computation? Normally, I've always gone for a maximum of 2*number of processing cores on a machine when compiling libraries, but generally for any in-built threading tasks I tend to stick to 1-to-1 vs cpu cores.

Comment: *My* general rule is to start with a factor of 1.5/2 high-CPU threads to processing units. This has generally worked well for me, but depends on actual code and hardware. Run some tests and be flexible.

Comment: Do you mean "1.5 CPU-intensive threads per 2 processing units" or "1.5 to 2 CPU-intensive threads per processing unit"?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades The latter case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TPL will automatically change how tasks are scheduled and add or remove ThreadPool threads over time.  This means that, given enough time and similar work, the default behavior *should* improve to be the best option.

By default, it will start by using more threads than cores, since many tasks are not "pure CPU".  Given that you're seeing extra tasks causing a slowdown, you likely either have resource contention (via locking), or your tasks are CPU bound, and having more tasks than processor cores will cause slowdowns.  If this is going to be problematic, you can make a custom [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that limits the number of tasks allowed at once, such as the [LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This allows you to limit the number of tasks to the number of processors in pure CPU scenarios.

If your tasks are bound by other factors, such as IO, then you may need to profile to determine the best balance between # of concurrently scheduled tasks and throughput, though this will be system specific.

Comment: THat is a great total non answer because you sort of miss the point that I think the OP has - that he asks how to plan this.

Comment: @TomTom I actually disagree - I did just edit to add more details, but a lot depends on what the tasks are doing.  Given the behavior the OP describes, it's most likely either resource contention or CPU bound, in which limiting the # of tasks can be beneficial.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Sorry to be late to the party; what I see today may not correlate with 2014; anyway... You *cannot* completely rely on the system to control number of concurrent tasks if their number is too high. In my case, there are potentially hundreds of tasks, and I have to let them run no more than, say, 8 at a time. If I start all of them, will be way slower. I was looking for algorithm to calculate that artificial max number. The program may run elsewhere, so I need to detect number of CPU cores and maybe other stuff at run time. Still looking.

Answer (score 7):

No, mostly becuase there is no definition of task. A task can be CPU intensive (limit is like Cores * factor), IO intensive (limit can be very low), or network intensivbe oto a limited ressource (which does not like to handle 1000 requests at the same time).

So, it is up for you as a programmer to use your brain and come up with a concept, then validate it and then put it into your program, depending on what the task actually IS and where the bottlenecks are foreseen. Such planning can be complex - very complex - but most of the time it is quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your tasks are CPU-intensive (i.e. they don't do a lot of I/O blocking such as reading files), you probably want to limit the number of parallel tasks to the number of CPU cores available to your application.  For example, if your application is running on a computer with a quad-core processor (i.e. 4 cores), limit it to 4 simultaneous tasks.

If your tasks are limited by something other than the CPU (e.g. disk access, network access, etc), then you'll need to figure out what share of that resource each task takes on average.  If you know the average then the number of tasks you should run to fully utilize your resource is `100 / average`.

Answer (score 0):

I came with this

Generally this is the guideline:

```
number-of-tasks = (task-total-run-time / task-cpu-bounded-run-time) * number-of-cores
```

For real calculation:

```
number-of-tasks = Ceil(Avg(task-total-run-time / task-cpu-bounded-run-time) * Max((number-of-cores - 1), 1))
```

**Explanation:**

`number-of-tasks` - the number of tasks to run in parallel

`task-total-run-time` - total run time of the async method in milliseconds

`task-cpu-bounded-run-time` - the time that the async method uses the core(s) cpu in milliseconds

`number-of-cores` - the number of real or virtual core ( in case of docker container for example ) that are available, there is a subtraction of `1` because one core is for the main thread and not a worker threads, for `1` core environments it will be minimum `1`

**Notes:**

- How to know the `Avg(task-total-run-time / task-cpu-bounded-run-time)`:
  A Measures need to be done in a real environment to figure out what is the average time ratio
- There should be some upper limit for maximum number of tasks even if they are almost fully not cpu bounded, for example `128`, this should
  be also taken into consideration

**Example:**

For `8` cores, and an average run is like this in terms of time

```
public async Task UpdateScoreAsync(string requestId)
{
    var res = await GetFromDB(requestId).ConfigureAwait(false); // not cpu bounded, 10 seconds

    int resScore = CalculateScore(res); // cpu bounded, 20 seconds

    await UpdateScoreInDB(requestId, resScore).ConfigureAwait(false); // not cpu bounded, 20 seconds
}
```

So the number of tasks you can run that are doing this ( if this is the only one you have ) are `12` tasks

```
12 = Ceil(((10 + 20 + 20) / (10 + 20)) * (8 - 1))
```